# Vary the Vpp of sinusoidal oscillator

Tags: voltage-regulator, oscillator, wien-bridge

For an assignment I have to create a sinusoidal oscillator with 5 Vpp (centered around 0 V) oscillating at 10.0 kHz. The oscillator works as expected, at the right frequency, but the voltage needs to be regulated between 0 to 5 Vpp.

The following picture shows my design so far;
[image: Wien-bridge oscillator with low pass filter]
As you can see the circuits consists of the Wien-bridge oscillator with a low-pass filter to attenuate the higher harmonics. I have tried using a voltage divider but that method does not hold for 0 to 5 Vpp. I am only allowed to use basic components, like the 741 opamp and 1N149 diodes, besides capacitors and resistors.

Does anyone know a method on how to achieve 0 to 5 Vpp regulation using these simple components?

Comment: It is unclear what needs to determine the amplitude. If it is simply "turning a knob" then I would add a potmeter at the signal output, similar to how an audio volume control works. If you need to control the signal amplitude from an external (DC) voltage then I do not see a solution with the allowed components.

Comment: Are you allowed to use a second opamp (as an inverting amplifier)?

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie That does make sense, but then I cant change my input voltage anymore, from 15 volts to say 20.

Comment: @LvW yes I am, as long as it does not add any substantial disturbance it should be okay.

Comment: *...but then I cant change my input voltage anymore, from 15 volts to say 20* You mean *supply voltage* instead of input voltage I guess. You can still change the supply voltage but the output voltage will then change as well. If that's not allowed then do not use voltage dividers (R5, R6, R7, R8) for amplitude limitation but replace R5 and R7 with a stack of diodes for example to get a more stable voltage.

Comment: Marinus...putting an inverting opamp at the output of the oscillator you can tune the gain between zero and any vakue you want (within upper limits) using a pot in the feedback loop of the second opamp.

Comment: It is very stupid of me that I did not think of that... Thank you @LvW this solved my problem, and I guess this will work great in practice too.

Comment: Marinus....regarding the RC lowpass - it is really necessary? If yes  - you should combine it with the second opamp: Realize the classical active first-order lowpass. The cut-off frequency is determined by the R2||C within the feedback path only. And with R1 at the input you can still tune the gain.

Comment: It would reduce higher harmonics which is useful, as we have to create the purest sine possible. Great idea on the active filter, but the gain would still be determined by A = -R2/R1, controlling, changing the gain using a potmeter R1 of 50k (only one available) would cause the gain to become infinite, or is my approach wrong here?

Comment: Marinus - you are right and I have made a stupid error. Sorry. Of course, the feedback resistor determines the cut-off frequency and cannot be used for gain tuning. What about filtering after the gain stage? However, in this case, perhaps additional buffering is necessary?

Comment: Marinus - please, can you show the form of the sinus signal without (before) lowpass filtering?

Comment: My question is because - as far as I can see - you have not chosen a "good" scheme for gain control. There are better methods, which - perhaps - allow to drop the lowpass filtering at the output.

Comment: Sorry for my late reply but... you are right, ofcourse, but I am bounded by the components I am allowed to use. I will post the answer of my question in a moment, as I managed to solve it using the inverting opamp. The filter was just to attenuate higher harmonics in the 20kHz - 50kHz range (the harmonics that a Wien-bridge oscillator generates), instead of a passive low-pass filter before the gain stage, I used a second-order Butterworth filter, and achieved an attenuation of -51.25 dB between 10 kHz and the highest apparent  harmonic (in practice, not even simulation).

Comment: This is the output of the oscillator (red) and after a passive low pass filter with fc of 10 kHz: https://imgur.com/WiSPKEg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, based on the comments, the voltage control was actually quite straightforward. Using a classic inverted amplifier. Where R11 is fixed based on input voltage, and R10 a potentiometer controlling the output voltage between 0 - 10 Volts which is halved by the second-order Butterworth filter.

[image]

Thank you for the help everyone!